# Update run_at for a delayed_job queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job

My application runs some jobs using delayed_job. It is a rails application running with mongoid. When an already queued job suddenly needs to change its schedule to start, can I just update the "run_at" field from the delayed_jobs collection for that specific job? Is there any better best practice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend updating the `run_at` attribute as it would mean touching the internals of a library.

Instead, consider setting the correct priority and using named queues on the `delay` method call.

If you use named queues, you can have a new thread dedicated to running such queues.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestion. Suppose that I name the queue, how to change its run_at only for that queue / job without internally change the run_at? Probably you could explain your the "new thread dedicated to running such queues" part

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Named-Queues-Proposal#commandline-changes) for command line options for running specific queue tasks.

Comment: Is there any way that I can access my queues (and/or specific named queue) via Delayed::Job class ? I prefer not to do it via terminal, instead, everything will be run in the ruby / rails application code

Comment: I believe so, I've enqueued to queues using `:queue` parameter. Check [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#named-queues) out.